# Card Game can't get my Win and Lose Div to appear in my IF statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I'm making a card game where you begin and the computer generates a card the player then must press a button either higher lower or equal to guess if the card is higher than the computers or lower or equal. 
This is my if statement in my script

```
if ((playerChoice == "higher") && (myCard2 > myCard) || 
   (playerChoice == "lower") && (myCard2 < myCard) || 
   (playerChoice == "equal") && (myCard2 == myCard)) {
   document.getElementById("Win").innerHTML = "You Win"
} else {
  document.getElementById("Lost").innerHTML = "You Lose"
}
```

Here is my html for the win and lose divs

```
<div id="Win"></div>
<div id="Lost"></div>
```

I just don't know why when i choose the higher button and the card is it won't show the You Win  and visa versa with all the buttons and for You Lost

Comment: Do the lines where you set the HTML get executed at all? Check with an `alert` perhaps?

Comment: have you checked all values are being set?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is the values are not being set for your javascript variables. Below is the test code I created to demonstrate the problem. You can change the values of the myCard2 and the myCard values and you will see the text change inside your div elements. If you are you using an on click event to gather your user input you will have to make sure it sets the javascript variables in order to make your code work.

jsfiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/u8kf796z/5/

```
/* test code inserted below*/

//set myCard2 value
var myCard2 = 9;

//set myCard value
var myCard = 8;

//set playerChoice value
var playerChoice = "higher";


/*end of test code*/

if  ((playerChoice == "higher") && (myCard2 > myCard) || 
    ( playerChoice == "lower") && (myCard2 < myCard) || 
    ( playerChoice == "equal") && (myCard2 == myCard)) 
    {
        document.getElementById("Win").innerHTML = "You Win"
    }


    else 

    {
        document.getElementById("Lost").innerHTML = "You Lose"


    }
```